# Python - Json not decoded

Tags: python, json, decode

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search'
results = requests.get(url)
br = results.json()
```

gives this error : Value Error : No Json object could be decoded

please advice...

Comment: Did you actually debug and take a look at the value? Or even used a `print` statement just to see? Does it contain anything in json format?

Comment: @Aditya it looks like this is your first question you've asked on stack overflow. Please review the points @ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for posting for improving this question and future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `http://search.twitter.com/search` in your browser, you get a message: `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.`

The reason you get the error you have is because calling GET on `http://search.twitter.com/search` did not return a JSON string.

If you run `requests.text`, you'll see the same message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting: Value Error : No JSON object could be decoded errors.

It means that the "results" of your Python Request could not be converted into JSON, which means there's an issue with the URL that you are requesting. Try a different URL.

Comment: This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545124/18145256).

Comment: @rachwa ; Can this question be closed out then? It seems odd having an abandoned, already answered question from 2015 open.